# How to add cover art to MP4?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I'm trying to find an effective way to update the metadata for my MP4 files that I plan to put on a DLNA server. First thing, I want to have the video files have a cover art.

I'm specifically using `640x360` JPG files to be the cover art.
I might also want to add some other tags, like media type or update the Title.  Please let me know what can be done.

If code suggestions are available, please know I have the file name details in a variable `%file%` to handle things. The JPG has the same name as the source MP4 file, so it's easy enough to get the file type and remove the extension, which is what I've done so far.

My goal is to be able to simply drop the MP4 file on the following batch file and know its filename and full path, the JPG file, and attach it to the orgininal MP4 file. Apparently `ffmpeg.exe` won't write to the file it pulled from, so I have it go to a temp file and then use MOVE to replace the old file with the fixed file.

```
@ECHO OFF
set arg=%1
set file=%arg:~1,-5%
ffmpeg -i "%file%.mp4" -i "%file%.jpg" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -map 0 -map 1:0 "%file%WIP.mp4"
move /Y "%file%WIP.mp4" "%file".mp4"
```

This code did not seem to work. It doesn't show up in Windows as the cover art, so I'd say it failed.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1357462/114058

Answer (score 0):

Can would do a try, by to change the argument and the position of **`-map 0 -map 1:0`** to immediately after name file input **`-map 1 -map 0`** along command line, so, this work to me...

Sorry my limited English.

```bat
@echo off & cd "%~dp0" && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for %%i in (%*) do ( 

     set "_arg=%%i"

     set "_file=!_arg:~1,-5!"

     if exist "!_file!.mp4" ffmpeg -i "!_file!.mp4" -i "!_file!.jpg"--map 1 -map 0  -acodec copy -vcodec copy "!_file!WIP.mp4" && move /Y "!_file!WIP.mp4" "!_file!".mp4"

     shift

    )
```